# watir click on javascript button

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I try to upload a file in web site, but i cant find a solution for click in the button, if i try

```
@@browser.button(:name => "submit_btn").when_present.click
```

i get this error 
/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)

Do you have an idea how i can click on the button ?

```
<center>

    <label for="tos"></label>
    <a href="tos.html"></a>
    <input id="tos" type="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){this.form.submit_btn.disabled=false}else{this.form.submit_btn.disabled=true};this.blur();" checked="" value="1" name="tos"></input>
    <br></br>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value=" Upload! " name="submit_btn"></input>

</center>
```

Comment: Based on the HTML, it looks like you'll need to click the TOS checkbox to enable the Upload! button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `browser.element(:name => 'submit_btn').click`